# development push notification works. Production does not

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I created a production and sandbox APNS certificate (one for both like apple says i can) but it only works when i use the sandbox gateway.

I have created an ad hoc provisioning profile (so i get a production device token when running the app) and archived and exported the app with that provisioning profile and my ios production identity (i just have them set in xcode before archiving).

I added it to my ipad but nothing happens when i send a push notification.

When i just install the app using xcode (getting a development devicetoken) i can send a push notification no problem using the sandbox gateway.

i looked at the ad hoc provisioning profile and i see 'production' under aps-environment.

I don't think i am missing anything but here we are.